# Create the Xpath for the following href for Selenium Webdriver

Tags: javascript, selenium

Please help me to create the Xpath for the following href. I am using Selenium webdriver and have only IE browser. Following is the HTML:
Need Xpath for : a href="javascript:OnEventQueue();">. 
I can use only IE browser and need to click on this link.

```
 <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML Transitional//EN"><META http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=windows-1252">

    <html>
    <body>
      <form name="runevent1" action="/epace/epace-cgi/eglcgids.exe?sessionid=" method="post" btnSubmit="javascript:preSumbit()" EParams="http://vaim1-apt-120/epace/epace-cgi/eglcgids.exe?sessionid=&Action=runevent1&EventType=&EventInst=#" EParamOptions="http://vaim1-apt-120/epace/epace-cgi/eglcgids.exe?sessionid=&Action=runevent1&EventType=&EventInst=#">
        <table width="100%" align="center" border="0">
          <tbody>
            <tr class="topMenu">
              <td align="right">
                <span id="idSpanActionLinks">
                  <a href="javascript:OnEventQueue();">
                    <font class="topMenu">Event Queue</font>
                  </a>
                </span>
              </td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </form>
    </body>
  </html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the following algorithms to select your elements.

#### CSS

```
element[attribute(^|*|$|~)='attribute value']
```

#### Xpath

```
//element[(@attribute|contains|starts-with|ends-with(@attribute, 'value'))='value'
```

The xpath is a little bit uglier, and definitely not correct, but the CSS algorithm is correct.

When you want to match on ANY property, including `href` like you want to, use this algorithm.

Ask yourself these questions:

1. what is the element I am selecting?
2. what is the attribute I am selecting?
3. is the attribute unique?

In your case, the answer to #1 is an `<a>`. Answer to number #2 is `href`.  Answer #3, is *probably not* because there could be more `href`'s like this.  whereas ID's, are usually unique. (it is called an *identifier* after all).  what you can do is look at the parent and use it's ID.

**In CSS**: `span#idSpanActionLinks > a` 
will work just fine.  (*`#` is just a css shortcut for id [see here](http://ddavison.io/css/2014/02/18/effective-css-selectors.html))

**In Xpath**: `//span[@id='idSpaceActionLinks']/a`

## EDIT

After your comment, since you are wanting to match `href`, here you go:

#### CSS

```
a[href*='OnEventQueue']
```

#### Xpath

```
//a[contains(@href, 'OnEventQueue')]
```

Both will work.

Note that both of these statements mean, in English:

> find me an `<a>` element, whose attribute `href` *contains* the value `OnEventQueue`

Comment: I have checked and span id is not unique , same for 3 links but I can see unique method name for each of the href and align property is unique. Could you please help to prepare CSS or Xpath of this :                                           <a href="javascript:OnEventQueue();">

Answer (score 0):

The XPath is not unique. For different levels of "precision", you can have different paths.

E.g.:

```
//*[@id="idSpanActionLinks"]/a
```

Comment: Xpath provided worked but there are 3 links with the same span id hence it has clicked on first link and did not click on the desired link.The desired link is on 2nd position.could you please help , how to click the next link which is having same span ID.<span id="idSpanActionLinks"><a href="javascript:OnEventQueue();">

    <font class="topMenu">Event Queue</font>

Comment: All href having same span id but I can see different align property ,can this help to identify and create a unique xpath to click Event Queue link.